# Table not coming inside the div but appearing out the box

Tags: html

I have been trying to include the table inside the `div`, but it seems not to be working. Here is my code:

```css
table {
  border: 5px red solid;
  border-style: double;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  background-color: azure;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  border: 5px red solid;
  border-style: ;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello this is for the practice.</p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your question answered? If not, please comment accordingly. If yes, please pick an answer. If you just don't care, at least please delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works better if you don't use the 'position' settings:

```
  <style>
    table {
      border: 5px red solid;
      border-style: double;
      background-color: aqua;
      /*position: absolute;*/
    }
    body {
      background-color: azure;
      text-align: center;
    }
    div {
      /*position: relative;*/
      border: 5px red solid;
      border-style: ;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: how will I then be able to change the position of the table if it is not inside the div?

Answer (score 1):

```
position: absolute;
```

removes an element from the document flow. That means that other elements just render as if the absolute positioned element wasn't there at all. Thus, the parent element just ignores the `table` in your code.

Aside from that, your question and what you want to achieve unfortunately is completely in the dark. Please add details as of what you are aiming to achieve.